# Dynamic Button Click in Table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, dynamic

Creating a dynamic button and linking it to the same event for all buttons created.

```
Private Sub PopulateNewOrders()
    Dim buttonNumber As Integer = 1
    For Each value In NewOrdersList
        Dim button As New Button
        button.ID = buttonNumber
        buttonNumber = buttonNumber + 1
        button.Text = "Cancel Order"
        button.CssClass = "CancelBtn"
        AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf CancelOrder_Click
        Dim Order As New TableRow
        Dim tempCell As New TableCell
        tempCell.Controls.Add(button)
        Order.Cells.Add(tempCell)
        CurrentOrderForm.Rows.Add(Order)
    Next
End Sub

Protected Sub CancelOrder_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim button As Button = sender
        Dim int As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(button.ID)
        showButtonPressedID.text = int
    End Sub
```

The CancelOrder_click event never triggers. I saw someone saying it needed to be protected so I tried that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use ID's like `1`,`2`,`3` but `BtnCancelOrder_1`,... You also have to re-create all dynamically created controls on every postback, otherwise even't aren't triggered.

Comment: This is a method i'm calling on the Page_Load so it should be called for all instances the page is loaded; Including postback.

Comment: but is `NewOrdersList` also re-initialized correctly to the total-count on every postback? Where is it stored, in ViewState, Session or a Hiddenfield?

Comment: Yes, I removed the part where I pulled the List from the session as well as adding each column with values. That's all showing correctly on my webpage. The only issue i'm having is none of the buttons are being bound to my click event. If I make a jquery function to make an alert on the css class "CancelBtn" the alert goes off fine. But I need the postback to change the session which is why i'm trying to get the button event working.

Comment: Try to move the code from `Page_Load` to `Page_Init`. The former might be too late for the events.

Answer (score 1):

`NewOrdersList` must be re-initialized correctly to the total-count on every postback. Where is it stored, in `ViewState`, `Session` or a `Hiddenfield`?

> Yes, I removed the part where I pulled the List from the session  ... This is a method i'm calling on the Page_Load so it should be called
>   for all instances the page is loaded; Including postback.

Try to move the code from `Page_Load` to `Page_Init`. The former might be too late for the events.